# Was the world created for the sake of Bikkurim or Torah?

Tags: midrash, creation, pentateuch-chumash, bikkurim-first-fruits

I was reading [*Let There Be Rain*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615188.html) and on page 8 it says the following:

"The world was created for the sake of the mitzvah of **bikkurim**,..." ([*Shemos* 34:26](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0234.htm#26))

Yet the  *Tikkunei Zohar* [78b] and [*Bereishis Rabbah*](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) (1:4) says, *"The world was created in the merit of the Torah..."*

Was the world created for the sake of *Bikkurim* or *Torah*?

Comment: I believe the medrash (cited by Rashi genesis 1:1?) also mentions that yisrael are called reishis and that the world was created for yisrael. If there was no Torah there would be no Bikkurim. If there was no Torah, there would be no Yisrael. If there was no Yisrael, there would be no Torah or Bikkurim.

Comment: See the first Noam Elimelech on Breishis, discusses this concept I think

Comment: Bishvil Reishis includes Yisrael, Torah, Moshe Rabbeinu, Bikkurim, Challah, and Terumah. How are those mutually exclusive? Let the world be created for them all combined.